# How do we calculate the mass of a scalar field that represents finite mass?

Tags: mass, field-theory

Since all scalar fields contain an infinite number of points with values assigned to each point, then a scalar field with finite mass could mistakenly add up to infinite mass because any positive value of mass time times infinity more or less equals infinity but is actually undefined. I ask, in the simplest mathematical breakdown as possible, how do we calculate the mass of a scalar field with finite mass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up two concepts.

The first concept is the *mass* of a *particle* associated with a field. When we say "a scalar field has mass $m$", what we mean is that quanta (fundamental excitations) of the field are spin-0 particles of mass $m$. In this case $m$ is (of course) a finite number.

The second concept is the *total energy* associated with a given field configuration. Because of $E=mc^2$, it is not unreasonable to associate a "mass" with a field configuration, and this can be meaningful when talking about special field configurations like solitons that have particle-like behavior. Typically there are boundary conditions that force the scalar field to reach its ground state (which we can assume has zero energy) asymptotically, so that the total energy of the field configuration is finite. However, you can imagine situations -- like a classical plane wave -- where the total energy is given by a finite energy density times an infinite volume, leading to an infinite total energy. Typically we think of this kind of situation as being a mathematical idealization of a more realistic situation with finite energy (for example, an infinite plane wave solution is often used as an approximation to the far field of a spherical wave), but mathematically there is nothing wrong with such solutions.

There is no direct connection between the total energy (or mass) of a specific classical field configuration, and the mass of a single quantum (aka particle) associated with the field. The total energy of a field configuration can be infinite (at least mathematically), the mass of a single particle should be finite.